# Using the UV4L driver to stream video from the raspberry pi camera to android phone

Tags: streaming-video, android, raspicam

Hello raspberry people!

I'm posting a new question because I don't have enough rep on raspberrypi.stackexchange to post a comment on this post:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/stream-video-from-rpi-cam-to-android-phone which sort of has a solution to my problem, only I cannot get it to work :(

In short, I want to control a robot from my Android, inside the robot is a raspberry pi with a raspberry pi camera. So for starters I want to just stream video from the robot to a java app on my phone.

.

The first comment on the aforementioned question links to [this post](http://sanjosetech.blogspot.com/2013/03/web-cam-streaming-from-raspberry-pi-to.html) which shows how to stream video from a Raspberry to an Android phone using a PS eye as camera.

The fourth comment by 'alex' says, regarding the use of a raspberry pi camera instead of a PS eye camera:

```
I've found the solution: I had to install the uv4l driver 
to use the RaspiCam as /dev/video0 and I had to modify the gst-server.sh : 
inserted videoscale !\ after ffmpegcolorspace !\ and it works :)
```

**So**
Im following this guide to install the uv4l driver on the raspberry pi:
http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14

Which i think is running these terminal commands:

```
wget http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/lrkey.asc && sudo apt-key add ./lrkey.asc
Adding line to apt sources -->> deb http://www.linux-projects.org/listing/uv4l_repo/raspbian/ wheezy main
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install uv4l uv4l-raspicam
sudo apt-get install uv4l-raspicam-extras
```

Now, if I quickly test the UV4L driver

```
dd if=/dev/video0 of=snapshot.jpeg bs=11M count=1
```

All I get is a totally black snapshot.jpeg

Also, if I try to restart the driver:

```
sudo service uv4l_raspicam restart
```

I get this warning:

```
pi@raspberrypi /etc/uv4l $ sudo service uv4l_raspicam restart
[....] Starting UV4L Raspberry CSI Camera Driver: uv4l
<notice> [core] Trying built-in driver 'raspicam'
<warning> [core] Driver 'raspicam' not found
<notice> [core] Trying driver plug-in 'raspicam'
<notice> [driver] Raspicam Video4Linux2 Driver v1.9.19 built Jul 12 2014
<notice> [driver] Selected format: 1920x1080, encoding: mjpeg, JPEG Video Capture
<notice> [driver] Framerate max. 30 fps
<notice> [driver] ROI: 0, 0, 1, 1
<notice> [core] Device detected!
<notice> [core] Loading the CUSE kernel module
<notice> [core] Registering device node /dev/video0
```

Any insight is gladly appreciated!
And, sorry for the longish post :(

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**For me I got it to work by running this:**

```
sudo apt-get install uv4l-server
sudo apt-get install uv4l-uvc
sudo apt-get install uv4l-xscreen
sudo apt-get install uv4l-mjpegstream
```

[Link url](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14)

Answer (score 3):

Now [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org) supports **Audio/Video streaming with `WebRTC`**, which allows you to get the live stream to your Android phone and/or other browsers.